# How to access a variable declared in yepnope.js from loaded JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yepnope

I have a yepnope.js file which loads several other JavaScript files.

In yepnope.js I have a variable called `applicationVersion`, which I append to the end of `load url` like this: `load: 'fileToLoad.js?v=' + applicationVersion` to enable cache busting!

Now I need to be able to access this `applicationVersion` from `fileToLoad.js` to enable cache busting for other functions within `fileToLoad.js`. Can I just access the variable from `fileToLoad.js` like the following?

```
//in fileToLoad.js
var ajaxUrl = '/json/messages?v=' + applicationVersion;
```

Or do I need other mechanisms to somehow pass the variable down from `yepnope.js` to `fileToLoad.js`?

I am not in an environment where I can test this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the `applicationVersion` with using a namespacing a variable.Hope this following snippet will help

Assuming this is your yepnope.js

```
var myYepnope = myYepnope || {} //Defining namespace;
    myYepnope.applicationVersion:"someVesrion";
    myYepnope.loader =function(){
      // code related to yepnope file loader
    }
    myYepnome.loader() // to execute the function
```

Now `applicationVersion` will be accessible from fileToLoad.js by calling `myYepnope.applicationVersion`

A change in value of `myYepnope.applicationVersion` will be reflected everywhere